# Get date from response headers in a POST request using Fetch

Tags: javascript, http-headers, http-post, fetch-api, response-headers

**UPDATED**

I am trying to get the Date from my response headers but only `Content-Type` is returned. Is it possible to get the date?

Here are my response headers after making a POST request:

[image: Network tab showing response headers]

Here is my utility function for making the POST request:

```
export default async function postData(url, func, audience, requestObj) {
    const accessToken = await func({
        audience: audience,
    });

    const myHeaders = new Headers();

    myHeaders.append('authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
    myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    const raw = JSON.stringify(requestObj);

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
        redirect: 'follow',
    };

    const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
    const transactionDate = response.headers.get('Date');

    //This returns null
    console.log('Date', transactionDate);

    //This returns only the Content-Type
    for (let pair of response.headers.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1]);
    }
    if (!response.ok) {
        if (response.status >= 500 && response.status <= 599) {
            throw new Error(
                'A server error occurred and we were unable to submit your data.'
            );
        } else if (response.status >= 400 && response.status <= 499) {
            const text = await response.text();
            throw new Error(text);
        } else {
            throw new Error(`${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
        }
    }

    const result = await response.json();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the end of `postData`:

> ```
> const result = await response.json();
> return result;
> ```

It doesn't return the response. It parses the response body as JSON and returns the resulting data structure.

That data structure doesn't include the headers. They exist on the `response` object.

If you want that data outside of `postData` then you'll need to read that value (`response.headers`) there and return it (possibly as part of an array or object that also includes the value of `result`).

Comment: Thanks Quentin. I updated my code with your suggestions (See above), but when I try to log `Date` it returns as `null` and when I try to log all of the headers, I only get back `content-type`.  

Any idea why it does not return `Date`?

Comment: It’s a cross origin request so JS can only read the exposed headers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments, `Date` in the response header is a `Forbidden Header Name` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) and cannot be accessed.

You can use `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) to expose the `Date` or if there is a concern about using `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` you can return a custom HTTP header with the date information instead.